# Cannot center X axis label using Chartist.js

Tags: chartist.js

I have a simple bar chart that I cannot get the x axis labels to center on the actual column.  Link to a [screen shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/545cW.jpg). Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="ct-chart" id="chart"></div>
    <script>
    new Chartist.Bar('#chart', {
      labels: ['Saved', 'Goal'],
      series: [
        [6000, 10000]
      ]
    }, {
      stackBars: true,
      width: 300,
      height: 250,
      axisX: {
        textAnchor: 'middle'
      },              
      axisY: {
        labelInterpolationFnc: function(value) {
          return (value / 1000) + 'k';
        }
      }
    }).on('draw', function(data) {
      if(data.type === 'bar') {

        data.element.attr({
          style: 'stroke-width: 70px'
        });

      }
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with Chrome so unless someone knows how to get it to work in IE, I will close the question.